# VSCode intellisense - Array of class instances

Tags: class, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm aware VS code's intellisense is powered by the TypeScript compiler however I'm not writing TypeScript, just good ol' ES2015.

Anyway VS Codes intellisense works well with ES6 class's however I'm coming unstuck where i have an array of classes. I dare say this would be out of the realms of the compilers ability but is there any way to write code to make it possible for the compiler to infer the types of objects stored in the array? A best guess as obviously they could be anything.

Here's my code to show you what i mean.

```
class JSONPayloadApi {
    constructor(payload) {
        this.apiName = payload.ApiName;
        this.apiRoot = payload.ApiRoot;
        this.apiTkn = payload.ApiTkn;
    }
}

class JSONPayload {
    constructor(value) {
        const payload = JSON.parse(value);

        this.apis = payload.Apis.map((x) => new JSONPayloadApi(x));
    }
}

// Pretend ive already created an instance of JSONPayload
const api = jsonPayLoad.apis[0];
```

In the above code is it at all possible for VS Code to infer that that `api` is infact an instance of `JSONPayloadApi` and provide intellisense accordingly?

The more i think about it the more i guess not, as we could after the fact add what ever we want to that array, destroying any meaning of the intellisense. Unless the array was frozen of cause.

This isn't mission critical or anything, more just a curiosity of the abilities of VS Code's intellisense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a better intellisense you can use a @ts-check comment in your javascript code. You will have to provide jsdoc comments to detial not inferred types. Like:

```
// @ts-check
let easy = 'abc'
easy = 123 // Error: Type '123' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Never forget that typescript and language service it provides are working only in compile time. There's no any restriction to "corrupt" data in runtime because of dynamic nature of javascript.

Comment: The `ts-check` comment seemed un-required, using `jsDoc` comments worked directly, thanks.